# How much weight does removing a vacuum system really save?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-maintenance, aircraft-systems, weight-and-balance

For a small GA aircraft (e.g. Piper, Cessna, Mooney), does anyone have a before and after weight savings example from removing a *vacuum system*?  E.g. calculated weight of component removal during W&B?

The context is replacing a standby attitude indicator with an electronic standby (e.g. MidContinent, Sandia SAI 340, etc)..

This question specifically refers to the vacuum system only, not the instruments themselves.  E.g. vacuum pump, hoses, fittings, etc.  Thanks!!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: See **Relevant Past Practice** for a brief overview of the "why":  http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgPolicy.nsf/0/6a24902ae5f1aeac86257ec1005b2fbc/$FILE/PS-ACE-23-08.pdf

Answer (score 7):

I removed the vacuum system in my VariEze a couple of years ago and saved 12 lb including the artificial horizon and heading indicator.  Probably about half of that was the instruments, the rest being in the pump/hose/regulator/filter/fittings.

Answer (score 3):

Just a random hunt, [this pump](http://www.aircraftspruce.eu/airpower-o-h-dry-air-pump-442cw.htm) (which I assume is the heaviest component) weighs 3-4 pounds.